# Cookie consent box on button click

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, css

I'm just getting started with frontend development. I tried to make a pretty barebones cookie consent notice. I still don't fully understand flexbox and positioning, so the code is messy.

HTML:

```
    <button id="shownotice">Click to ask</button>
<div id="consent_elem" class="consent_notice" hidden="true">
    <p>Are you fine with cookies?</p>
    <div id="buttons">
        <button class="consent_button" id="yes">Yes</button>
        <button class="consent_button" id="no">No</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#shownotice {
    background-color: cyan;
    border:0;
    padding: 5px;
}


[hidden] { display: none !important; }

.consent_notice {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    bottom:0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#buttons {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 5px;
}

.consent_button {
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: gray;
    border: 0;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

JS:

```
show_button = document.querySelector("#shownotice");
consent_elem = document.getElementById("consent_elem");

show_button.onclick = (e) => {
    consent_elem.hidden = consent_elem.hidden ? false : true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## IDs

Avoid IDs for styling. It's ok to use them to identify elements with JavaScript, but the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) in CSS can make structuring the styles tricky.

Names such as `buttons`, `yes` and `no` are very generic, that could easily be needed more than once in a document.

Also try to be more consistant with the style of classes/names/IDs. For example, `shownotice` has no underline, but `consent_notice` does. Consider using hyphens instead of an underlines in order to match the general style of CSS, which uses hyphens, as in `background-color`.

## HTML

`"true"` is not a valid value for the attribute for the attribute `hidden`. As a [boolean attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute) `hidden` is either present without a value (or, if you prefer use the value `"hidden"` as in `hidden="hidden"`) or not present. `hidden="false"`, for example, would still hide the element.

## JavaScript

Declare your variables with `const` or `let` (or `var` if you need to support very old browsers).

In JavaScript it is convention to write variable names in camelCase and not with underlines.

You could be more consistent when retrieving elements by ID and use either `querySelector` or `getElementById`, but not both.

Don't use `on...` properties to assign event handlers. Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Use the boolean negator `!` to toggle boolean values:

```
consent_elem.hidden = !consent_elem.hidden;
```